# How to print count and print numbers of modelname in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as `vehicles`

```
id  name  categoryname  brandname    model
1   juy   car           toyota       121
2   gty   van           nissan       caravan
3   bgh   car           bmw          520d
4   hyu   van           ford         max
5   nhj   car           toyota       121
6   gtr   car           toyota       corolla
7   gtr   van           nissan       caravan
```

i am using following controller function to display categorynames with bransnames

```
public function filterbrand ()
    {
        $vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')
                    ->orderBy('categoryname', 'asc')
                    ->get();

                  return view('vehicles.brand')->withVehicles($vehicles);
```

and use following blade file to show data

```
<?php $cat = ""; ?>
@foreach($vehicles->unique('modelname') as $vehicle)
   @if($vehicle->categoryname != $cat )
            <?php $cat = $vehicle->categoryname; ?>
             {{$cat}}
            <br><br>
     @endif
     <ul>
    <li>{{$vehicle->brandname}}</li> <br>

  </ul>
@endforeach
```

this is printing this types outputs

car
toyota
121
toyota
corolla
bmw
520d

van
nissan
carvan
ford
max

but now I need print also modelnames with its counting like this

car
toyota
121(2)
toyota
corolla(1)
bmw
520d(1)

van
nissan
carvan(1)
ford
max(1)

how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the count with the group by in order to get the model with count:

```
public function filterbrand ()
    {
        $vehicles = DB::table('vehicles')
                    ->select('categoryname','brandname','model', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->orderBy('categoryname', 'asc')
                    ->groupBy('model')
                    ->get();

      return view('vehicles.brand')->withVehicles($vehicles);
    }
```

Comment: this got following error ** (2/2) ErrorException

Undefined property: stdClass::$brandname (View: C:\Users\banda\Desktop\testing\testing\resources\views\vehicles\brand.blade.php)

Comment: let me know which your problem is solved or not with the updated answer

Comment: can you comment about this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692713/how-to-get-datas-vice-categoryname-from-controller-in-laravel-5-6