# How to get datas vice categoryname from controller in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as `vehicles`

```
id  name  categoryname  brandname    model
1   juy   car           toyota       121
2   gty   van           nissan       caravan
3   bgh   car           bmw          520d
4   hyu   van           ford         max
5   nhj   car           toyota       121
6   gtr   car           toyota       corolla
7   gtr   van           nissan       caravan
```

i am using following controller function to display categorynames with brandnames and modelnames

```
$buss = DB::table('vehicles')
                    ->select('categoryname','brandname','modelname', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->orderBy('categoryname', 'asc')
                    ->groupBy('modelname')
                    ->get();

                    return view('vehicles.bus')->withBuss($buss);
```

and use following blade file to show data

```
<?php $cat = ""; ?>
@foreach($vehicles->unique('modelname') as $vehicle)
   @if($vehicle->categoryname != $cat )
            <?php $cat = $vehicle->categoryname; ?>
             {{$cat}}
            <br><br>
     @endif
     <ul>
    <li>{{$vehicle->brandname}}</li> <br>

  </ul>
@endforeach
```

this is showing data as following,

car
toyota
121(2)
toyota
corolla(1)
bmw
520d(1)

van
nissan
carvan(1)
ford
max(1)

but now I need change something, that means first give categorynames as using following controller function,

```
$names = Vehicle::groupBy('categoryname')->select('id', 'categoryname', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();
```

and blade file

```
@foreach($names as $name)
        <a href="{{ route('vehicles.brand') }}">{{$name->categoryname}}</a> 
    @endforeach
```

and now categorydata showing with hyperlink as following,

car
van

now I need when click above categoryname showing data related to categoryname fron the `vehicles` table. following controller is working manually for car category

```
$car = DB::table('vehicles')
                    ->select('categoryname','brandname','modelname', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                    ->orderBy('categoryname', 'asc')
                    ->groupBy('modelname')

                    ->where('categoryname', 'car')
                    ->get();

                    return view('vehicles.bus')->withCar($car);
```

but I can't find out how to automatically set each categoryname data in controller when click above categotyname? can you give me some solution here?

Comment: No any answers here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the question is not easy to understand, you should edit it and make the problem more easy to understand.

what i understood is that you need to show vehicles that has the `categoryname` clicked in the link above right?

if it is like that, then you must change some of your code like this.

first you must add the `categoryname` to your url like this

```
    @foreach($names as $name)
        <a href="{{ route('vehicles.brand',['cat' => $name->categoryname]) }}">{{$name->categoryname}}</a> 
    @endforeach
```

then in your route you must have something like this

```
Route::method('your/route/url/{cat}','YourController@yourMethod)->name('vehicle.brand');
```

the important part is to add the route param `{cat}` to your route, the rest is up to you.

then in your controller you get the param like this

```
public function yourMethod(Request $request, $cat) {
    //finally you add the $cat variable to your query like this
    $car = DB::table('vehicles')
                ->select('categoryname','brandname','modelname', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                ->orderBy('categoryname', 'asc')
                ->groupBy('modelname')

                ->where('categoryname', $cat)
                ->get();

                return view('vehicles.bus')->withCar($car);
}
```

and presto, you are now filtering the query by `categoryname`

if that is not what you needed, then please reformulate your question.